# Phrase meaning "To have passed or currently be at"

Tags: phrases, ambiguity

I have 40 characters, (broken up into two lines of 20,) to send hints to users about the location of a "prize" buried somewhere in a grid.

There is ambiguity when I tell the user if, at any time during the exercise, they have visited the same square as the prize. Previously I would send one of these messages:

---

```
You have not passed
   the prize yet.
```

---

```
  You have already
  passed the prize.
```

---

If the user has *just* entered the same square as the prize, it should count as a pass. This is problematic, because the phrasing of the hint makes most users believe they have already missed it, while it's entirely possible the prize is currently below their feet.

Users agree that a "pass" involves walking into the prize's square, *then walking away from it* - which is not what I mean to imply.  This is confusing for everyone, but I can't seem to rephrase the hint without it becoming more confusing, or completely giving away the position of the prize.

How could I unambiguously convey this in 40 characters or less?

Comment: This is off topic per our [help], both because it's a request for writing advice and because this Q&A is so narrow that it will not be useful to anyone else.

Comment: What about saying "You have been near the prize"?

Comment: @jwpat7 "Near" tends to confuse users further.  They aren't certain what qualifies proximity, such as being a square away from the prize.

Comment: Ok, "You have been on the prize" or "You have visited the prize" or "You visited the prize square"

Comment: @MετάEd This Q. is *very* similar to [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119327/phrase-meaning-north-but-not-directly-north-from-here), which has been 'protected'. I don't disagree that this may be OT, but, as the two are so similar, I don't see how one can be protected and the other be OT.

Comment: @TrevorD Questions get protected when they attract large numbers of low-quality answers. Protection is not reserved just for good questions. Questions which request writing advice often attract lots of low quality answers and need protection even though they're not a good fit for the site.

Comment: @MετάEd OK. Thanks for the info. I thought it was ones that were thought 'significant'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the users aware that the playing field is divided into squares? If so, perhaps something like this:

> You have been on
>   the prize square

If they are not square aware, perhaps simply:

> You have been [or stood]
>   where the prize is

Or are the squares large enough that entering the square where the prize is does not necessarily mean you are “where the prize is”?

Comment: Excellent question; Yes, they are square-aware. I'm a strong advocate of square awareness and prevention.

Comment: @Doc, that rather sounds like a political statement from _Flatland_!

Comment: Looks like you're two for two.  Users clearly understand the message now.

Answer (score 0):

How about *arrived at*?  I personally would choose *hot* and *cold* for *close* and *far*.  That's a very common children's usage in America, which adults would understand immediately.

Comment: The hints are designed to be useless on their own, but combined with other types of hints allow users to eventually deduce the location of the prize. "Arrived at" seems to imply the users are definitively on top of the prize, instead of it being just a possibly.

Answer (score 0):

*You were or are on the prize square* would be one way to say it.